# Linux console: only kernel messages are printed

Tags: linux, console, serial-console

My Linux system is built by Buildroot and runs on a Raspberry Pi.
I use a Usb to TTL Serial cable to get a console.

Here comes cmdline.txt

```
dwc_otg.fiq_fix_enable=1 sdhci-bcm2708.sync_after_dma=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0
console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait
```

Here comes the getty related part of /etc/inittab

```
# Put a getty on the serial port
ttyAMA0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  ttyAMA0 115200 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
```

Only kernel messages are printed; no daemons ones (such as sshd).

How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: Actually, just reordering the 2 entries works too, as the last `console` element seems to be assigned as the primary logging console by `systemd` (serial consoles are not just used in SBCs (like the Pi), but a lot in servers in data centres too). That is, `console=tty1` __before__ `console=ttyAMA0,115200`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console` is specified twice in that cmdline:

```
console=ttyAMA0,115200
console=tty1
```

Perhaps the second one has overridden the first (it can't be both at the same time).  If `ttyAMA0` is what you want to use, remove `console=tty1`.